# Linear combination of the elements of a basis $\beta$ with respect to another basis $\beta'$ in a vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider an $n$ dimensional vector space $V$ with two ordered bases $\beta=\{v_1,v_2,....,v_n\}$ and  $\beta'=\{v_1',v_2',....,v_n'\}$. Suppose for $1\le j \le n$ \begin{equation}v_j'=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_{ij} v_i \end{equation} 
Show that the $n\times n$  matrix $A$ defined by $A_{ij}=\alpha_{ij}$ is invertible.

(The result, being an important one, may have already been asked in the site. I haven't seen it. Still, if the exact same question or almost similar question has been raised, I urge the scholars to mark it as duplicate. Those answers might help me in understanding the problem in a better way. Below, I am presenting what I did while I asked the same in an interview)

***What I attempted:-***

I would use the fact that $A$ is invertible if its $n$ columns are linearly independent.
Let the $j^{th}$  column of $A$ be $A_{*j}=\begin{bmatrix} \alpha_{1j} &\\
\alpha_{2j} &\\ 
\vdots &\\
\alpha_{nj} 
\end{bmatrix} $

$A_{*j}$ 's are independent if \begin{equation}  \begin{aligned}
\sum_{j=1}^n a_j \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_{1j} &\\
\alpha_{2j} &\\ 
\vdots &\\
\alpha_{nj} 
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 0 &\\ 
0 &\\ 
\vdots &\\  
0 
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow a_j=0  \qquad .......(1)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Now, $v_j$'s form basis. Thus we have, \begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned} 
\sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j'=\textbf{0} \Rightarrow a_j=0 \qquad .......(2) \end{aligned} 
\end{equation} 
Now, \begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned} 
& \sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j'=\textbf{0} \\
\Rightarrow & \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_{ij} v_i \right)=\textbf{0} \\
\Rightarrow & \sum_{i=1}^n  \left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \alpha_{ij} \right) v_i=\textbf{0} \\
\Leftrightarrow & \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \alpha_{ij}=0 \qquad (\mbox{$v_i$'s are independent}) 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

which is just the system of linear equations expressed in $(1)$. So, 
$\sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j'=\textbf{0} \Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \alpha_{ij}=0$

Thus from $(2)$ we have, 
$\sum_{j=1}^n a_j \alpha_{ij}=0 \Rightarrow a_j=0$, $\qquad 1\le i \le n$

So, $A_{*j}$'s are linearly independent. Hence $A$ is invertible.

Am I correct ?

Comment: I think there is a typo in your definition of $A_{*j}$ shouldn't the value of the column be $\alpha_{ij}$ instead of $\alpha_{1j}$? Anyway I have some trouble understanding what you asume and what you want to proove in your demo. I'll have a second read, but I'm pretty sure there is a more straightforward proof.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I didn't notice it. Edited accordingly. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit after your comment:*

If I should use $(2)\Leftrightarrow(1)$ then you should too. In your demonstration, you only uses "$\implies$", and never "$\Leftrightarrow$". However, you implications **are** equivalences, you just have to show it. I just changed it, and added a $"\forall"$ quantifer.

\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned} 
& \sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j'=\textbf{0} \\
\Leftrightarrow & \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_{ij} v_i \right)=\textbf{0} \\
\Leftrightarrow & \sum_{i=1}^n  \left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \alpha_{ij} \right) v_i=\textbf{0} \\
\Leftrightarrow & \forall i \in \{1,..,n\}, \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \alpha_{ij}=0 \qquad (\mbox{$v_i$'s are independent}) 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

From this the proof sound good to me.

Now, just for a bit of nitpicking, I think you should write it on the other way, so you don't have to jump from one equation to another:

\begin{equation}  \begin{aligned}
\sum_{j=1}^n a_j \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_{1j} &\\
\alpha_{2j} &\\ 
\vdots &\\
\alpha_{nj} 
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 0 &\\ 
0 &\\ 
\vdots &\\  
0 
\end{bmatrix}
\implies
& \forall i \in \{1,..,n\}, \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \alpha_{ij}=0 \\
\implies
& \sum_{i=1}^n  \left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \alpha_{ij} \right) v_i=\textbf{0} \\
\implies
& \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_{ij} v_i \right)=\textbf{0} \\
\implies
& \sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j'=\textbf{0} \\
\implies
& \forall j \in \{1,..,n\}, a_j=0 \qquad \mbox{(from $\beta'$ being a base)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

---

*Original message*

I don't think you proof is correct.

You have 3 propositions:

$$\text{(1)    }\sum_{j=1}^na_jA_{*j}=0$$

$$\text{(2)    }\sum_{j=1}^na_jv'_j=0$$

$$\text{(3)    }\forall j \in \{1,..,n\}, a_j =0 $$

You're trying to prove 
$$(1)\implies(3)$$

From $\beta'$ being a base, you have $$(2)\implies(3)$$

And it seems like the rest of your proof is prooving $$(2)\implies(1)$$

Therefore you have $(2)\implies(1)\land(3)$ but not $(1)\implies(3)$

---

Two other ways to prove it without any calculation needed

**(1)**

Since $$\forall i \in \{1,...,n\}, v'_i = A*v_i$$

You have

$$IM(A)=SPAN(\beta')=V$$

Therefore $KER(A)=0$, so A is invertible

**(2)**

Just notice that your $A_{*j}$ column is nothing more than $v'_j$ coordinates expressed in $\beta$ base. Since $\beta'$ is a base too, ${v'_j}'s$ are linearly independant, and so are your columns

Comment: I think I should write $(2) \Leftrightarrow  (1)$

Comment: @Bhargob Ok, I think I get it, edited this way

Comment: Thanks Carette for helping me in understanding the question as well as in assisting me to improve the answer. The reverse way that you provided seems much more better than mine. After reading your edit and judging my own answer, I think I would modify my principal step as follows:-

Comment: \begin{equation} \begin{aligned} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j' &=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_{ij} v_i\right) \\ &=\sum_{i=1}^n  \left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \alpha_{ij} \right) v_i \end{aligned} \end{equation} If $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j' =\textbf{0} $ then  $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j' =\sum_{i=1}^n  \left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \alpha_{ij} \right) v_i=\textbf{0}$, which  follows from the above equality . Now, $\sum_{i=1}^n  \left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \alpha_{ij} \right) v_i=\textbf{0} \Leftrightarrow  \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \alpha_{ij} =0$ (We must note that this is an  "if and only if" relation)

Comment: Thus $$ \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \alpha_{ij} =0 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j'=\textbf{0} \Rightarrow a_j=0$$   $$ \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \alpha_{ij} \Rightarrow a_j=0$$ for all $j=1,2,.....,n$. (Because the relation "$\Rightarrow$" is transitive.) It completes our proof.

Answer (score 1):

Transform the bases in the other way around. 
So let $v_j=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \beta_{ij}v_i'$, and produce the matrix $B$ with these coefficients. 
Then $AB=I_n$ (clear if you combine the two systems of equations).

You might be interested in this: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis